# Autodesk Forge get access token

Tags: autodesk-forge

Can some help me understand what I've typed incorrectly to create a **read & write** token.  I have types zeros in my client id and client secret for my security so I know that isn't the problem. If you can show me a clear example that would be helpful. I've been stuck for a while. Autodesk sample only has a read example.

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' 
-X 'POST' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-d 'client_id=00000000000000000000000000000000&
client_secret=0000000000000000&
grant_type=client_credentials&
scope=data:read, data:write, bucket:create, bucket:read'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace ', ' by '%20'. This is because you say the data is x-www-form-urlencoded.

curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' 
-X 'POST' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-d 'client_id=00000000000000000000000000000000&
client_secret=0000000000000000&
grant_type=client_credentials&
scope=data:read%20data:write%20bucket:create%20bucket:read'

Comment: Thank you so much.  haha I've been spinning my wheels for sometime now.